# Solve $\sqrt{\dfrac{a}{x}}-\sqrt{\dfrac{x}{a}}=\dfrac{a^2-1}{a}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Solve $\sqrt{\dfrac{a}{x}}-\sqrt{\dfrac{x}{a}}=\dfrac{a^2-1}{a}$

Let $u^2=\dfrac{a}{x}$:

$\Rightarrow \sqrt{u^2}-\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{u^2}}=\dfrac{a^2-1}{a} \tag{1}$

$\Rightarrow u-\dfrac{1}{u}=\dfrac{a^2-1}{a} \tag{2}$

$\Rightarrow a(u^2-1)=u(a^2-1) \tag{3}$

$\Rightarrow au^2-a^2u=a-u \tag{4}$

$\Rightarrow au(u-a)=a-u \tag{5}$

$\Rightarrow -au(a-u)=a-u \tag{6}$

$\Rightarrow -au=1 \tag{7}$

$\Rightarrow u=\dfrac{-1}{a} \tag{8}$

Therefore $\dfrac{1}{a^2}=\dfrac{a}{x} \Rightarrow x=a^3$. However $x=\dfrac{1}{a}$ is given as another answer, but I don't see how it's possible to derive this solution from my calculations.

Comment: You dividide by $a-u$. What is the exception when cancelling a common factor from an equation needs extra care?

Comment: Have you considered the fact that $$\sqrt{x^2}\neq x$$ but instead $$|x|$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First if
\begin{equation}
a - \frac{1}{a} = b - \frac{1}{b}
\end{equation}
then $a - b = \frac{b - a}{a b}$, hence $b\in\{a, -\frac{1}{a}\}$ because if $b\not = a$ we may divide by $b-a$ to obtain $-1 = \frac{1}{a b}$. Also note that $a$ and $-\frac{1}{a}$ have opposite signs.

In your case we must have $\sqrt{\frac{a}{x}} = b > 0$, so there are two cases:

- if $a> 0$ then $b = a$ and $x = \frac{a}{a^2} = \frac{1}{a}$
- if $a < 0$ then $b = -\frac{1}{a}$ and $x = a^3$

Answer (score 1):

Is the $u$ substitution needed? Consider the following:

$\sqrt{\frac{a}{x}}-\sqrt{\frac{x}{a}}=\frac{a^{2}-1}{a}$

Now, re-write the RHS as $a-\frac{1}{a}$ and square both sides (this is the part that I'm not totally sure is valid) to give:

$\frac{a}{x}+\frac{x}{a}-2=a^{2}+\frac{1}{a^{2}}-2$

$\frac{a^{2}+x^{2}}{x}=\frac{a^{4}+1}{a}$

$a x^{2}-(a^{4}+1)x+a^{3}=0$

$(x-a^{3})(ax-1)=0$

$x=a^{3}$ or $x=\frac{1}{a}$

Comment: I skipped a few steps I thought were obvious. Did I miss something?

Comment: This works, apart from the small error described by @PeterPhipps , but it is reasoning by implication. You need to check at the end whether your solutions are solutions of the original equation, which is not always the case.

Answer (score 0):

Now:
$$
\sqrt{\frac{a}{x}} - \sqrt{\frac{x}{a}} = \frac{a^2 - 1}{a}
$$
multiply by $a$
$$
a\sqrt{\frac{a}{x}} - a\sqrt{\frac{x}{a}} = a^2 - 1
$$
Set $t=a/x$
$$
a\sqrt{t} - a\sqrt{\frac{1}{t}} = a^2 - 1
$$
solve for $t$ by squaring
$$
a^2t-2a^2+a^2/t=a^4-2a^2+1
$$
$$
a^2t^2+a^2-a^4t-t=0
$$
$$
a^2t(t-a^2)-(t-a^2)=0
$$
and finally
$$
(t-a^2)(a^2t-1)=0.
$$
As the product is $0$ each factor can be rearranged to get a root:
$$
t_1=a^2, t_2=1/a^2
$$
Now the resubstitution yields the answers
$$
x_1=1/a, x_2= a^3.
$$

Answer (score 0):

###### Question Summary (for Easier Reference)

Solve: $$\sqrt{\dfrac{a}{x}}-\sqrt{\dfrac{x}{a}}=\dfrac{a^2-1}{a}
=a-\dfrac{1}{a}
\text{ for }x\text{ in terms of }a \tag{Eq. 1}$$

###### Solution Steps

Start by observing that the roles of $\sqrt{\frac{a}{x}}$ and $a$ are very similar, and same with $-\frac{1}{a}$ and $-\sqrt{\frac{x}{a}}$.  So try this solution and check for consistency:
$$\sqrt{\frac{a}{x}}=a\text{ , } \tag{Eq. 2a}$$
$$ -\sqrt{\frac{x}{a}}=-\frac{1}{a} 
\tag{Eq. 2b}$$
$$\tag{Eqs. 2}$$
Testing Equation 2a, namely $\sqrt{\frac{a}{x}}=a$ and simplifying it by multiplying the left and the right by $\sqrt{x}$:
$$
\sqrt{a}=a*\sqrt{x}
\underset{implies}\implies \pm\sqrt{x}=\frac{1}{\pm \sqrt{a}} 
\underset{implies}\implies x=\frac{1}{a} \tag{Eqs. 3a}
$$
Now test Equation 2b for consistency, namely
$-\frac{1}{a}=-\sqrt{\frac{x}{a}}$ thus:
$$-\frac{1}{a}=-\sqrt{\frac{x}{a}}
\underset{implies}\implies \frac{1}{a}=\sqrt{\frac{x}{a}}
\underset{implies}\implies \frac{1}{a^2}=\frac{x}{a}
\underset{implies}\implies x=\frac{1}{a}
\tag{Eqs. 3b}$$
$$\tag{Eqs. 3}$$
Obviously the sign of $x$ and $a$ must be the same so that $\sqrt{\frac{x}{a}}$ and $\sqrt{\frac{a}{x}}$
are irrational numbers greater than $0$ and not a product of $\sqrt{-1}=i$.

Thus, Equation 1 indeed has the solution:

$$ 
\boxed{x=\frac{\displaystyle 1}{\displaystyle a}}
\tag{Eq. 4}$$